# Detect the horizontal mousewheel

Tags: jquery

I would like to make a differenciation between three cases :

```
e.preventDefault();
if(Mousewheel.direction = Left)
    base.goForward();
else if(Mousewheel.direction = Right)
    base.goBack();
else{   
    //Doing normal slide
```

But I can't find anything indicating if the mousewheel is horizontal or vertical, the only returns of the plugin Mousewheel, being delta and event.

If someone knows how i could make a differenciation between horizontal and vertical wheeling, thanks for sharing your tips.

Comment: you know most mouses do not have the horizontal scrolling options?

Comment: @Topener I'm sure OP is aware of that, yes. He just wants to detect it when it does exist.

Comment: The wheel on my mouse can be tilted but that action triggers the "Back" / "Forward" commands in my browser...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I tested it with my laptops pad and `event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaX` is indeed your answer.

Using some javascript debugging tools, place a breakpoint into the event handler and examine the event object.

[image]

There are some interesting properties there like `event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaX` and `event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY`. I don't have a mouse with horizontal scrolling to test it but possibly this is your solution.

Comment: Hey cool, 
Thanks a lot, it was exactly what I was searching for, I didn't know we could actually use breakpoints in JavaScript, that will help me a lot.

Comment: every time a new user doesnt accept a correct answer, john resig kills a plugin

Answer (score 0):

Most scrollwheel drivers have an option that changes vertical scrolling to horizontal when the shift key is held down. Try detecting that instead.

Comment: I just discovered that ATL + mousewheel decreases the scrolling speed which can be useful. Btw SHIFT + mousewheel jumps between pages in my case (Firefox + Logitech mouse).

Comment: Shift+Scroll scrolls though my history in Opera.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in IE9, IE10, Firefox, Safari and Chrome. The different browsers currently each have a different event you need to register (although they will all eventually converge upon the new W3C standard onwheel event).

In another answer I put a [bunch of detail about detecting x-axis scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821985/detecting-mousewheel-on-the-x-axis-left-and-right-with-javascript/12850780#12850780).